how to manipulate two different applications that should communicate with each other on two different emulators at the same time (webdriverio)?
I have two applications one is for customer the other is for pickers. Once the customer has inserted his order, the picker app should receive a notification where if approved the customers order status will change.
I am trying to automate the above scenario, however I am unable to run the two apps at the same time on two different emulators.
On run the apps are opening on a single emulator and failing one after the other without consideration of the order of the apps should open, noting as well that the apps should not both open on the same emulator. And finally I am getting this error:
`in "0: Given A user is on the toters app home tab"invalid session id: The session identified by 6bb7ce21-dcdd-49ee-b5b3-bd9b56abb8a1 is not knownat getErrorFromResponseBody (file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:195:12)at NodeJSRequest._request (file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/request/index.js:193:23)at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)at async Browser.wrapCommandFn (file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:90:29)at async Browser.$ (file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/node_modules/webdriverio/build/commands/browser/$.js:74:17)at async Browser.wrapCommandFn (file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:90:29)at async Common.accessHomePage (file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/features/pageobjects/mobile/android/common/common.ts:29:18)at async World.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/features/step-definitions/mobile/android/dark-store/order.ts:10:5)at async wrapPromiseWithTimeout (C:\Users\Toters\Desktop\toters-automated-tests\node_modules@cucumber\cucumber\src\time.ts:55:10)at async Object.run (C:\Users\Toters\Desktop\toters-automated-tests\node_modules@cucumber\cucumber\src\user_code_runner.ts:86:16)[0-0] 2024-05-02T16:01:33.285Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()[0-0] 2024-05-02T16:01:33.285Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()[0-0] 2024-05-02T16:01:33.286Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://0.0.0.0:4723/session/9bf0b941-f990-41bb-804e-afca003d57fe[0-0] 2024-05-02T16:01:33.286Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://0.0.0.0:4723/session/de7d06d8-b0e7-4752-9021-ecd7dd50ebee[0-0] 2024-05-02T16:01:33.786Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null[0-0] 2024-05-02T16:01:33.863Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null[0-0] FAILED in MultiRemote - file:///C:/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/features/features/mobile/dark-store/place.order.feature2024-05-02T16:01:33.987Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook2024-05-02T16:01:33.987Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Given I have two android emulators up and running
customer-app, picker-app
Given I have already runned the appium command in my terminal by so booting appium server on the port 4723
Given the ports 4728 and 4729 are free
Given I have the following capabilities in my android.conf.ts file
capabilities: {
    customerApp: {
      capabilities: {
        platformName: "Android",
        "appium:app":
          "/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/apps/app-staging-debug.apk",
        "appium:platformVersion": "11",
        "appium:deviceName": "customer-app",
        "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
        "appium:systemPort": 4728, // It's good to specify different system ports if running multiple sessions
      },
    },
    pickerApp: {
      capabilities: {
        platformName: "Android",
        "appium:app":
          "/Users/Toters/Desktop/toters-automated-tests/apps/picker-staging-build.apk",
        "appium:platformVersion": "11",
        "appium:deviceName": "picker-app",
        "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
        "appium:systemPort": 4729, // Example of a different system port
      },
    },
  },

and Given that I have edited the following type file: node_modules@wdio\types\build\index.d.ts to use the capabilities anywhere in my code:
 declare global {     namespace WebdriverIO {             interface MultiRemoteBrowser {                 myAppiumDriver: WebdriverIO.Browser                 myChromeDriver: WebdriverIO.Browser             }         interface MochaOpts {             [key: string]: any;         }         interface JasmineOpts {             [key: string]: any;         }         interface CucumberOpts {             [key: string]: any;         }         interface ServiceOption extends Services.ServiceOption {         }         interface ReporterOption extends Reporters.Options {         }         interface Config extends Options.Testrunner {         }         interface HookFunctionExtension {         }         interface WDIODevtoolsOptions {         }         interface WDIOVSCodeServiceOptions {         }         interface BrowserRunnerOptions {         }         interface ChromedriverOptions extends DriverOptions {         }         interface GeckodriverOptions extends DriverOptions {         }         interface EdgedriverOptions extends DriverOptions {         }         interface SafaridriverOptions {         }     } }

and Given I have declared the two capabilities as well in my node_modules\webdriverio\build\types.d.ts for the multiRemoteBrowser
interface MultiRemoteBrowser extends MultiRemoteBrowserType { customerApp: WebdriverIO.Browser; pickerApp: WebdriverIO.Browser; }

And Given I have a common.ts file where I am writing my code
I have declared the following
const { customerApp, pickerApp } = multiremotebrowser;

and this is my function that I am trying to boot both devices
  async accessHomePage() {
    while (
      !(await customerApp
        .$("[resource-id = 'com.toters.customer.staging:id/btnGetStarted']")
        .isExisting())
    ) {
      console.log("waiting for get started button to appear");
    }
    while (
      !(await pickerApp
        .$("[resource-id = 'com.toters.customer.staging:id/btnGetStarted']")
        .isExisting())
    ) {
      console.log("waiting for get started button to appear");
    }
  }


Check the comments, probably it's not possible to use 2 appium servers for 1 device:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/testing-multiple-apps-in-one-device-first-session-is-terminated-when-second-starts/37776
